# If $A$ is regular, then so is $A[T]$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I would like to solve an exercise in Bourbaki's *Algèbre Commutative* (chapter 8, §5) stating that $A[T]$ is regular whenever $A$ is.
We argue as follows (the book gives the idea of the argument):

- $A[T]$ is Noetherian by the Hilbert basis theorem
- "by localizing we may reduce to the case where $A$ has finite global dimension"
- Then $\operatorname{gldim}A[T]=\operatorname{gldim}A+1$ is finite, hence $A[T]$ regular.

I don't quite understand how one can do the second step. I mean if we take a prime ideal $p$ of $A[T]$, I think $A[T]_p$ need not be isomorphic to $A_p[T]$ (which doesnt even make sense unless $p$ comes from a prime ideal of $A$). Can we express $A[T]_p$ as a polynomial ring?

Comment: If $P$ is a prime ideal of $A[T]$, and $p=P\cap A$, then $A[T]_P=A_p[T]_Q$ where $Q=S^{-1}P$ with $S=A\setminus p$. (I find quite inappropriate to say "some standard commutative algebra book" instead of giving the exact reference.)

Comment: The second point suggests to localise $A$,  not $A[T]$. As $A\to A[T]$ has the *lying-over* property, each localisation of $A[T]$ is a regular local ring.

Comment: @Bernard so you are essentially referring to the fact that if $A\rightarrow B$ is faithfully flat, $A$ and the fibres are regular, then $B$ is regular (or something related to this)? I think I know this argument, I just want to do it the way suggested by the book. As usual, thank you  user26857 for sharing your knowledge with me. I think this explains it very nicely.

Comment: I don't really need this stuff: you just have to know that, for any ideal $I$ in $A$,  $A[T]/IA[T]\simeq A/I[T]$, and the *definition* of a local ring is that all its localisations at maximal ideals are regular local rings.